# Varios objetos en una misma coordenada geográfica

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-v3

Tengo varios objetos en una misma coordenada (por ejemplo, varios comercios en un centro comercial donde la coordenada es la puerta de entrada). Cuando los presento en el mapa, los marcadores se ponen uno sobre otro, sólo tengo acceso a hacer click sobre el primero y no puedo ver los que están detrás.

Agradecería si alguien puede darme una idea de cómo salir de esto. Estoy usando la API de Google Maps V3.

Answer (score 1):

En el sitio en inglés, hay [algunas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7092085/3695983) [preguntas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1538681/3695983) [similares](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/15436) en las que se recomienda hacer uso de los **[Google Maps API Libraries](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html)** y en particular el [MarketClusterer](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html), que lo que hará es agrupar marcadores hasta cierto nivel de zoom.

Por ejemplo ([demo original aquí](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/simple_example.html)):

```js
function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var markers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
      dataPhoto.longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/images/m'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#map-container {
  padding: 6px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
  width: 600px;
}

#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>

<div id="map-container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

---

Pero esa solución tiene un problema que te afectaría directamente: si los marcadores tienen exactamente las mismas coordenadas, va a llegar un momento que aunque hagas zoom, se van a seguir poniendo los unos sobre los otros que es lo que quieres evitar.

...Y aquí es donde entra en juego otro plugin para Google Maps que se creó en parte para corregir ese comportamiento: **[Overlapping Marker Spiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier)** para Google Maps API v3.

En la página web del plugin, se comenta que se diseñó para emular el comportamiento de Google Earth, en el cual, si los marcadores se solapan, se puede pulsar en uno y se separan (algo que aunque puede no ser el efecto que buscas, podría servirte para lo que quieres).

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo ([demo original aquí](https://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo-1.html)):

```js
var mapLibsReady = 0;

function mapLibReadyHandler() {
  if (++mapLibsReady < 2) return;

  var mapElement = document.getElementById('map_element');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
    center: {
      lat: 52,
      lng: -1
    },
    zoom: 7
  });
  var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {
    markersWontMove: true, // we promise not to move any markers, allowing optimizations
    markersWontHide: true, // we promise not to change visibility of any markers, allowing optimizations
    basicFormatEvents: true // allow the library to skip calculating advanced formatting information
  });

  for (var i = 0, len = window.mapData.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function() { // make a closure over the marker and marker data
      var markerData = window.mapData[i]; // e.g. { lat: 50.123, lng: 0.123, text: 'XYZ' }
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerData
      }); // markerData works here as a LatLngLiteral
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_click', function(e) { // 'spider_click', not plain 'click'
        iw.setContent(markerData.text);
        iw.open(map, marker);
      });
      oms.addMarker(marker); // adds the marker to the spiderfier _and_ the map
    })();
  }

  window.map = map; // for debugging/exploratory use in console
  window.oms = oms; // ditto
}

// randomize some overlapping map data -- more normally we'd load some JSON data instead
var baseJitter = 2.5;
var clusterJitterMax = 0.1;
var rnd = Math.random;
var data = [];
var clusterSizes = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 18, 24];
for (var i = 0; i < clusterSizes.length; i++) {
  var baseLon = -1 - baseJitter / 2 + rnd() * baseJitter;
  var baseLat = 52 - baseJitter / 2 + rnd() * baseJitter;
  var clusterJitter = clusterJitterMax * rnd();
  for (var j = 0; j < clusterSizes[i]; j++) data.push({
    lng: baseLon - clusterJitter + rnd() * clusterJitter,
    lat: baseLat - clusterJitter + rnd() * clusterJitter,
    text: Math.round(rnd() * 100) + '% happy'
  });
}
window.mapData = data;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: auto;
}

p {
  margin: 0.75em 0;
}

#map_element {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=mapLibReadyHandler"></script>
<script async defer src="https://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js?spiderfier_callback=mapLibReadyHandler"></script>

<div id="map_element"></div>
```

Comment: Mil gracias Alvaro, excelente tu aporte.